# MyBatis multi-datasource configuration issue

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

*Using mybatis 3.2.8 ,Spring 3.2.9 release,mybatis-spring 1.2.2 to configure my project's DAO and the project need to convenient both mysql and oracle so i use the databaseIdProvider to adapt multi-datasource here is my configuration:*

1. datasource

```html
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName">
    <value>xxxxx</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

2. vendorProperties

```html
<bean id="vendorProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="properties">
    <props>
      <prop key="SQL Server">sqlserver</prop>
      <prop key="DB2">db2</prop>
      <prop key="Oracle">oracle</prop>
      <prop key="MySQL">mysql</prop>
      <prop key="H2">h2</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

3. databaseIdProvider

```html
<bean id="databaseIdProvider" class="org.apache.ibatis.mapping.VendorDatabaseIdProvider">
  <property name="properties" ref="vendorProperties" />
</bean>
```

4. sqlSessionFactory

```html
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="databaseIdProvider" ref="databaseIdProvider" />
  <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"></property>
</bean>
```

*because mysql's paging is different from oracle's so i wrote two ways of paging and depends on runtime environment to chose to use which.here is the mapper.xml:*

```html
<sql databaseId="oracle" id="PagePrefix">
  <!--
          WARNING - @mbggenerated
          This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
        -->
  <if test="page != null">
    select * from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from (
  </if>
</sql>
<sql databaseId="mysql" id="PagePrefix">
  <!--
          WARNING - @mbggenerated
          This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
        -->
  <if test="page != null">
    select * from (
  </if>
</sql>
```

*and use it like this:*

```html
<select id="selectByExample" parameterType="xxx.xxx.xxx" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
  <!--
          WARNING - @mbggenerated
          This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
        -->
  <include refid="PagePrefix" />select
  <if test="distinct">
    distinct
  </if>
  from xxx
  <if test="_parameter != null">
    <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
  </if>
  <include refid="PageSuffix" />
</select>
```

*the above is all my configuration.
when i am running the query operation or any other DML,the console will print:*

```html
org.apache.ibatis.builder.IncompleteElementException: Could not find SQL statement to include with refid 'xxx.xxx.xxx.PagePrefix'
```

*i find this exception was caused by org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.sqlFragments did not had the value that the key is 'PagePrefix'.
so i following the blow steps to find what is wrong:*

1. *my local environment is oracle,so i modified the mapper.xml, removed the mysql config just left the oracle config:*

```html
<sql databaseId="oracle" id="PagePrefix">
  <!--
              WARNING - @mbggenerated
              This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
            -->
  <if test="page != null">
    select * from ( select row_.*, rownum rownum_ from (
  </if>
</sql>
```

*but it's also not work,the exception still remained.*

2. *then i thought maybe the mybatis did not recognized my runtime environment,so i looked into the source code to find out the whether the information was set into the mybatis or not.i find the startup class `org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean#buildSqlSessionFactory()` method has:*

```html
    if (this.databaseIdProvider != null) {
          try {
            configuration.setDatabaseId(this.databaseIdProvider.getDatabaseId(this.dataSource));
          } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new NestedIOException("Failed getting a databaseId", e);
          }
        }
```

*and i toggled breakpoint in here and find the value was right.*

3. *Then i started to find where and when the sqlFragments was assigned value.i found that sqlFragments was assigned when parsing the mapper.xml: `org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder#configurationElement()`*

```html
     private void configurationElement(XNode context) {
        try {
          String namespace = context.getStringAttribute("namespace");
          if (namespace.equals("")) {
           throw new BuilderException("Mapper's namespace cannot be empty");
          }
          builderAssistant.setCurrentNamespace(namespace);
          cacheRefElement(context.evalNode("cache-ref"));
          cacheElement(context.evalNode("cache"));
          parameterMapElement(context.evalNodes("/mapper/parameterMap"));
          resultMapElements(context.evalNodes("/mapper/resultMap"));
          sqlElement(context.evalNodes("/mapper/sql"));
          buildStatementFromContext(context.evalNodes("select|insert|update|delete"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new BuilderException("Error parsing Mapper XML. Cause: " + e, e);
        }
      }
```

*and the method `sqlElement` do the actual assign value on sqlFragments and according the databaseId to find the tag ''*

```html
    private void sqlElement(List<XNode> list, String requiredDatabaseId) throws Exception {
        for (XNode context : list) {
          String databaseId = context.getStringAttribute("databaseId");
          String id = context.getStringAttribute("id");
          id = builderAssistant.applyCurrentNamespace(id, false);
          if (databaseIdMatchesCurrent(id, databaseId, requiredDatabaseId)) sqlFragments.put(id, context);
        }
      }
```

*but in that time the databaseId hasn't been set yet beacuse the parsing phase is before the setDatabaseId operation what i mentioned before.
Now i have no idea how to solve this problem.does any people encountered the same situation like me?*

Comment: Are you sure that all namespaces are correct? What is the namespace of the fragment where PagePrefix is declared? when you reference a fragment defined in antoher file the referenced id must contain the namespace

Comment: tks in advance,i removed the the databaseId  attribute of the sql tag and it not throw exception at all,so the namespaces are correct i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that problem was causing that i wrote the mappers tag in mybatis-config.xml so that the mybatis will do it's own configure and despite Spring's configure.so if you want to use multi-datasource through Spring that you can not write the mybatis' own config xml.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to create a working sample. The trick was getting the right map for the properties. You must be able to specify what the

```
DataSource().getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName()
```

returns and user it as the key in your property file
my mapping for postgres is

```
<bean id="vendorProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="PostgreSQL">postgres</prop>
            <prop key="Oracle">oracle</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

PostgresSQL is the result of

```
DataSource().getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName()
```

In the mapping file I have

```
<sql databaseId="postgres" id="PagePrefix">
    select sum(a) from (
</sql>
```

and it's correctly loaded